# splitting string with "- " delimiter using sed not working

Tags: shell, sed, split

I have below string, each line delimited by New Line as Input string

```
string="name: MAIN_ROLE
description: ROLE DESCRIPTION
readOnly: 
roleReferences:
- roleTemplateAppId: app1
  roleTemplateName: template2
  name: Name1
- roleTemplateAppId: app2
  roleTemplateName: template2
  name: Name2
"
```

I like to print YAML string into comma delimited string as below result. Input string could have any number of component after "-" which makes new record but MAIN_ROLE value remain the same first column:

```
MAIN_ROLE,Name1,template1,app1
MAIN_ROLE,Name2,template2,app2
```

I tried below code to split the line with "- " but I am not getting correct result

```
echo "$a" | sed -n $'/^- $/,/^- $/p' <<< $string
```

Comment: Don't use `sed` to parse JSON.

Comment: I think string is YAML not the JSON. I do not thing Bash has anything built in which allows me to parse these type of string. I think I will have to split string delimited by "- " and store in Array and split further using ":" to get final result but I am stuck with first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` this way:

```sh
awk 'NR==1{a=$2;cnt=0} /^-/{rta[cnt]=$3;getline;rtn[cnt]=$2; getline; n[cnt]=$2;cnt++} END{ for(i=0;i<cnt;i++) { print a","n[i]","rtn[i]","rta[i] } }' file > outputfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Na5V9U):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
string="name: MAIN_ROLE
description: ROLE DESCRIPTION
readOnly:
roleReferences:
- roleTemplateAppId: app1
  roleTemplateName: template1
  name: Name1
- roleTemplateAppId: app2
  roleTemplateName: template2
  name: Name2
"
awk 'NR==1{               # When on Line 1
    a=$2;cnt=0            # Set a (main name) and cnt (counter) vars
}
/^-/{                     # When line starts with -
    rta[cnt]=$3; getline; # Add role template app ID to rta array, read next line
    rtn[cnt]=$2; getline; # Add role template name to rtn array, read next line
    n[cnt]=$2;cnt++       # Add name to n array, increment the cnt variable
}
END{                      # When the file processing is over
    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++) {  # Iterate over the found values and... 
        print a","n[i]","rtn[i]","rta[i]  # print them
    }
}' <<< "$string"

# => MAIN_ROLE,Name1,template1,app1
#    MAIN_ROLE,Name2,template2,app2
```

Comment: I like to write final lines in file within awk but my outside variable of fullfilepath is not recognized. I tried printf a","n[i]","rtn[i]","rta[i] >> "$fullfilepath" but did not work. How do I pass $fullfilepath to awk command so it can write to given file ?

Comment: @LordOfTheRing You need to pass variables to awk like this: `awk -v fullfilepath="$fullfilepath"...`

Comment: I did like this and still does not work:   awk -v fullfilepath="$fullfilepath" 'NR==1 {               
    a=$2;cnt=0 
}
/^-/{             
    rta[cnt]=$3; getline; 
    rtn[cnt]=$2; getline; 
    n[cnt]=$2;cnt++       
}
END{                      # When the file processing is over
    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++) {  # Iterate over the found values and... 
 
  printf a","n[i]","rtn[i]","rta[i] >> "$fullfilepath"   # print to file
    }
}' <<< "$string"

Comment: @LordOfTheRing [It works](https://imgur.com/a/GP5OxWo) on my end. But now I realize you are not using it right, just use `awk 'NR==1{a=$2;cnt=0} /^-/{rta[cnt]=$3;getline;rtn[cnt]=$2; getline; n[cnt]=$2;cnt++} END{ for(i=0;i<cnt;i++) { print a","n[i]","rtn[i]","rta[i] } }' <<< "$string" > "$fullfilepath"`. Updating a file line by line is not efficient. Unless you have some specific requirements, like writing each line to a separate file, I'd rather redirect the awk output to a file directly.

Comment: It worked, I was using "$fullfilepath" inside awk instead of fullfilepath . Thanks

Comment: It is only returning Subaccount if full value is Subaccount Administrator in any of the fields, Specially roleTemplateName and Name field. Looks like after space it is not returning values.

Comment: @LordOfTheRing Change the field separator then, to `awk -F': '...`. Or to a regex, `awk -F':[[:space:]]+'...`.

Comment: I am really not expert in awk. Where do I apply your suggestion in code  awk -F':[[:space:]]+' ?

Comment: Thanks, that worked but created another problem. Removed last field and gave me output like this : MAIN_ROLE,Name1 extra1,template1 extra2,

Comment: @LordOfTheRing Right, the fields will be just two in each case, so you need to replace `rta[cnt]=$3` with `rta[cnt]=$2`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/0Sp26A).

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, you could try following `awk` program. This could be simply done with few conditions rather than using array systems.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ OFS="," }
/roleTemplateAppId/{
  if(name && template){
    print "MAIN_ROLE",name,template,$NF
  }
  name=template=""
}
/roleTemplateName:/{
  template=$NF
  next
}
/name:/{
  name=$NF
}
END{
  if(name && template){
     print "MAIN_ROLE",name,template,$NF
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ OFS="," }                          ##Setting OFS to , in BEGIN section.
/roleTemplateAppId/{                      ##Check if line contains roleTemplateAppId then do following.
  if(name && template){                   ##check if name and template is SET then do following.
    print "MAIN_ROLE",name,template,$NF   ##Printing MAINE_ROLE name, template and last field value here.
  }
  name=template=""                        ##Nullifying name and template here.
}
/roleTemplateName:/{                      ##Check if roleTemplateName: is found in current line then do following.
  template=$NF                            ##Setting template to last field of current line.
  next                                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/name:/{                                  ##Checking condition if line contains name: then do following.
  name=$NF                                ##Setting name value as last field name.
}
END{                                      ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(name && template){                   ##check if name and template is SET then do following.
     print "MAIN_ROLE",name,template,$NF  ##Printing MAINE_ROLE name, template and last field value here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for great logic and explanation. I am almost illiterate in awk command.